# How to echo php variable with text inside a function call?

Tags: php, variables, echo

Using the thumbsup script to generate ratings for various things. Here is the current code:

```
echo ThumbsUp::item($reviewid)->template('mini_thumbs2')->format('{UP} out of {TOTAL} people found this review helpful')
```

I'm trying to add the text `review_` before `$reviewid`. No matter what I try, Dreamweaver will stop showing errors, but the variable doesn't pass through. Last thing I tried is:

```
echo ThumbsUp::item('review_$reviewid')->template('mini_thumbs2')->format('{UP} out of {TOTAL} people found this review helpful')
```

Comment: I'd accept at least `5` of your answers to your other `6` questions...

Comment: Can you post the code for `format()` (from `ThumbsUp::item`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using double quotes? Variables (and this is the rule for Perl too) won't interpolate into strings unless you use double quotes.

```
//                  v- double quotes-v
echo ThumbsUp::item("review_$reviewid")->template('mini_thumbs2')->format('{UP} out of {TOTAL} people found this review helpful')
```

Alternatively, you could use string concatenation to do the same thing:

```
echo ThumbsUp::item('review_' . $reviewid)-> ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you escape variables with curly brackets, as this approach allows you to use object variables, example:

```
echo ThumbsUp::item("review_{$reviewid}")->template('mini_thumbs2')->format('{UP} out of {TOTAL} people found this review helpful');
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not expanded within '', only within "".

```
echo ThumbsUp::item("review_$reviewid")->template('mini_thumbs2')->format('{UP} out of {TOTAL} people found this review helpful');
```